# How to load different data classes from Parse into uitableview with UISegementedControl -> Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

Fairly new to Parse backend and coding all together...

I am trying to implement a `UISegmentedControl` within a viewcontroller to load different Parse classes (User Products, User Services, User Favorites) into a `uitableview`. *`uitableview` covers only half of the `viewcontroller`*

I am wondering what is the best approach to properly implement this function?
Please forgive me if my question seems too vague.

Thank you!

Comment: `UISegmentedControl` for loading Parse classes? That doesn't sound promising...could you share some implementation details - maybe some code?

Comment: I don't mean actually load Parse classes. I mean display different Parse classes w/n a uitableview. I have not implemented any code yet, because I wanted to know what the best approach would be.

Comment: Basically when a user changes the segmentedcontrol state, I want to display different parse classes w/n the uitableview. Hope I explained it a little better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution should have three components:

1. Detect changes in your UISegmentedControl
2. Load the appropriate data with a query
3. Update the UITableView

   **1. Detect Changes in your UISegmentedControl**
   You can find an excellent tutorial here on implementing and detecting changes: http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-segmented-controluisegmentedcontrol-tutorial/

   **2. Load the appropriate data with a query**
   https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries is where you can learn about how to format your queries for different Parse classes. Use a `switch` statement to decide which class to load.

   **3. Update the TableView**
   This one is the easiest. Use a global variable for your Swift class that stores the returned objects from the `PFQuery`. If you need to use different cell layouts for the classes, use a `switch` statement with your UISegmentedControl's index to determine how to load the data appropriately in your UITableView's `cellForIndexPath:` method.

Sorry I can't be more specific, but hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! Just what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome! (Also, it's usually good etiquette to mark an answer correct AND add an upvote for it. You don't have to if you don't think it's warranted, but it's usually nice to do so. I wouldn't mention it normally but you seem like you might be new here)

Comment: I am a newbie, but thank you for mentioning that. I will be sure to do so!